# How to convert this where filter from Oracle Sql to Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

How to write this where clause filter of the Date in Teradata sql?
My objective is to make sure every time the code runs in any year, it picks up the most recent data from July of Previous year to June of current year.
I already have the filter created in Oracle sql. I just need to convert it to Teradata.

```
select *
from C.Data DM
Where

DM.Dateofdata between 
To_Date (‘01-07-‘ || To_Char(Extract(Year from SysDate) -1), ‘DD-MM-YYYY’)

and 
To_Date(‘30-06-‘ || To_Char(Extract(Year from SysDate)), ‘DD-MM-YYYY’)
```

I tried the Oracle sql code but the filter doesn’t work in teradata

Comment: Simply replace `SysDate` with Standard SQL `current_date`

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite similar to the old oracle code

```
select *
from C.Data DM
WHERE DM.Dateofdata 
BETWEEN DATE (EXTRACT(year FROM current_date) - 1) || '-07-01'
AND DATE EXTRACT(year FROM current_date) || '-06-30' ;
```